# How would I fix the error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() in the following code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, project, valueerror

So I'm doing a project on Datacamp where I have to analyze SAT scores from NYC public schools. Here are the instructions they gave me:

> Create a pandas DataFrame called best_math_schools containing the "school_name" and "average_math" score for all schools where the results are at least 80% of the maximum possible score, sorted by "average_math" in descending order.
>
> Identify the top 10 performing schools based on scores across the three SAT sections, storing as a pandas DataFrame called top_10_schools containing the school name and a column named "total_SAT", with results sorted by total_SAT in descending order.
>
> Locate the NYC borough with the largest standard deviation for "total_SAT", storing as a DataFrame called largest_std_dev with "borough" as the index and three columns: "num_schools" for the number of schools in the borough, "average_SAT" for the mean of "total_SAT", and "std_SAT" for the standard deviation of "total_SAT". Round all numeric values to two decimal places.*

The error I got from datacamp was

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

and I looked online for ways to fix this, but nothing worked.

And here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in the data
schools = pd.read_csv("schools.csv")

# Preview the data
schools.head()

best_math_schools = schools[['school_name', 'average_math']]
best_math_schools = best_math_schools[(best_math_schools['average_math'] >= 640)]
best_math_schools = best_math_schools.sort_values(by='average_math', ascending=False)
print(best_math_schools)

top_10_schools = pd.DataFrame()
top_10_schools['school_name'] = schools['school_name']
top_10_schools['total_SAT'] = schools['average_math'] + schools['average_reading'] + schools['average_writing']
top_10_schools = top_10_schools.sort_values(by='total_SAT', ascending=False)
top_10_schools = top_10_schools.head(10)
print(top_10_schools)

total_SAT = pd.DataFrame()
total_SAT['school_name'] = schools['school_name']
total_SAT['borough'] = schools['borough']
total_SAT['total_SAT'] = schools['average_math'] + schools['average_reading'] + schools['average_writing']

largest_std_dev = pd.DataFrame()
largest_std_dev = schools.set_index('borough')
columns_to_drop = ['school_name', 'percent_tested', 'building_code',  'average_math',  'average_reading',  'average_writing']
largest_std_dev = largest_std_dev.drop(columns=columns_to_drop)
largest_std_dev['num_schools'] = schools.groupby('borough')['school_name'].count()
largest_std_dev = largest_std_dev.drop_duplicates()
largest_std_dev['average_SAT'] = total_SAT.groupby('borough')['total_SAT'].mean()
largest_std_dev['average_SAT'] = round(largest_std_dev['average_SAT'], 2)
largest_std_dev['std_SAT'] = total_SAT.groupby('borough')['total_SAT'].std()
largest_std_dev['std_SAT'] = round(largest_std_dev['std_SAT'], 2)
print(largest_std_dev)
```

And here is the Dataframe provided as well as the results from my code:

The Dataframe "schools" that was provided
[image: The Dataframe "schools" that was provided]

The result of my code
[image: The result of my code]

I tried added `.all()` to the end of the line

```
best_math_schools = best_math_schools[(best_math_schools['average_math'] >= 640)]
```

but that gave me an error instead. And also tried making an if-else statement with `.any()` which didn't change the outcome of the code. My code is working like it should as it is doing everything that datacamp is telling it to, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on that line. Are you sure that's the line that's getting the error? Please show the full traceback.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

schools = pd.read_csv("schools.csv")

schools.head()

best_math_schools = schools[schools["average_math"] >= 640][["school_name", "average_math"]].sort_values("average_math", ascending=False)

schools["total_SAT"] = schools["average_math"] + schools["average_reading"] + schools["average_writing"]

top_10_schools = schools.groupby("school_name", as_index=False)["total_SAT"].mean().sort_values("total_SAT", ascending=False).head(10)

boroughs = schools.groupby("borough")["total_SAT"].agg(["count", "mean", "std"]).round(2)

largest_std_dev = boroughs[boroughs["std"] == boroughs["std"].max()]

largest_std_dev = largest_std_dev.rename(columns={"count": "num_schools", "mean": "average_SAT", "std": "std_SAT"})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).